# WinForm off screen preventing

Tags: c#, winforms

Following my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531088/form-move-inside-client-desktop-area)

I'm able to prevent winform off screen when user make some drag-drop, 
however I notice that when I move my form, mouse cursor seems running fastly, more than winForm, in fact, when Drag-Drop is finished mouse cursors appears in a position off form. 
Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: Fastly? I wouldn't say so; it's just that you *can* move the cursor off the form when the form hits the invisible border, because the cursor, unlike the form, is not restricted in its movements. Is it not what you observe?

Comment: No. I mean this scenario occurs whan winform is inside desktop client area too. Note that I said "cursor is in a position off FORM", NOT off desktop area. When drag drop is finished I aspect cursor inside form area, at the same original point, but it isn't.

Comment: So you're moving the form, it does move as it hasn't hit a border, but the cursor still moves relative to the form? That should be happening. Do you have any interfering code in `form_move` or such? Do you see this behaviour if you create a new clean project and paste [just that code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11531392/11683) into the form?

Comment: No, I have not any interferencing in any events. You can see my issue, use the same code you posted me, then try to move form from position to another one and you'll see mouse cursor is not over the form, but out of it. (this occurs when you move form fastly).

Comment: No, I can't reproduce that. Unless you hit the form against a screen border, the cursor does not move relative to the form.

Comment: Surely, you will be able to see my issue by moving the form (quite fastly) right to left AND left to right. Please try this so you'll be able to understand me.

Comment: I have moved and shaken the form quite vigorously, in all directions, including left to right and back. It just does not happen *unless I accidentally hit the form against the screen border*.

Comment: @bit Does this involve custom code which moves the window based on mouse movements - such as in a MouseMove type of routine?

Answer (score 1):

[This mdsdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) will tell you how to move the cursor.

However, based on the previous post you've pointed to, it looks like you're doing a lot of fooling around with windows.

Unless you're dealing with a computer that will be used in public by people who may walk up and mess it up for the next person, you'll probably fine such things frustrate the user more than they help.

A very novice user may lose your app's window accidently, but they're going to have to figure that out eventually if they are an employee who's going to use the PC everyday.

Meanwhile you will be frustrating - and making mad - anybody who's used to the computer.

Also you're making more work for yourself and not getting any extra functionality.

I'm not sure what you're trying do of course I could be way wrong on this, but usually, it's both easier and better to not play with such things.

Comment: I've done some other test. my issue occurs becouse m.LParam is minor of zero, but when I move my form in a fastly way, it's not seem going to off screen (that will be cause a negative integer).

Comment: @bit `lParam` is a pointer, not a value. Btw, I have updated the code in that question to fix an unrelated bug, but see if it magically fixes your behaviour as well.

Comment: No, the problem is still alive..but maybe it is only something that my eyes cannot see in real time. Just as you've said, the issue occurs (obviously) when form is dragged off the screen. When I try to move the form (fastly way) I think to don't go off the screen but unknowingly I just go there. Ok, please consider close this post and thank you again for your new code.

Comment: ..Sorry..Just one thing: is it possibile prevent mouse move event when the offscreen has occurs? In this way I can solve the above issue.