# Form off Screen - Cursor off Form Area

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567016/winform-off-screen-preventing)

I've thought a "simple" solution.
My goal is to prevent mouse movement when my winForm has reached the allowed coordinates. 
For instance, if offScreen is for maxX (right border), user will can move mouse in all direction except for left to right.

Is there some event (native too) to accomplish that?

Comment: Cursor.Clip property.  Treating the user like an idiot never turns out well.

Comment: Cursor.Clip needs for a Rectangle Area and that's is not what I'm looking for. If you starts with drag operation, you have clicked on some position of form, for instance 10X - 30Y. Well, those value should be the same at drag-Drop complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# want to restrict where a form can be moved to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885266/c-sharp-want-to-restrict-where-a-form-can-be-moved-to)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Now I need to prevent mouse movement when winForm has reached dekstop border limits. Cursor.Clip works almost fine, however there are 2 problems: 1, I note a sort of flickering, 2 I need to Click 2 time in order to be able to move form on another direction. i use clic function like this: Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y), new Size(0, 0));